# Function return will not render Links in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-dynamodb, return

I want to map an array of titles as links that display in React. The titles come from a DynamoDB table that I turn into an array of React links.

I was able to successfully map the titles as links. I am able to see the return in the console.log. I am just unable to see the links render as I expect them too. I want to see these titles as links on the page. Even if I replace the return of my DisplayTitles function with Hello World in paragraph tags, I see nothing render. I even tried to wrap them like a list with no luck.

What did I miss? This seems like it should be straight forward, but here I am. I looked at other return issues here, but had no luck in finding a solution for my challenge. Thanks for your help.

Here is my index.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

This is my App.js file:

```
import { React } from 'react'; 
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Home} from './components/Home';
import {About} from './components/About';
import {DisplayTitles} from './components/AwsFunctions';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to='/'>Home</Link></li>
        <li><Link to='/about'>About</Link></li>
        <DisplayTitles tableName="recipes"/>
      </ul>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' exact element={<Home/>} />
        <Route path='/about' element={<About/>} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}

export default App;
```

And this is the problematic AwsFunctions.js file:

```
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

AWS.config.update({
    region: 'some where',
    endpoint: 'out there',
    accessKeyId: 'key',
    secretAccessKey: 'secret'
  });

const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()

export function DisplayTitles(props) {

    var params = {
        ProjectionExpression: "title",
        TableName: props.tableName
    }

    docClient.scan(params, function (err, data) {
        if (data) {

            const links = data['Items']
            const listLinks = links.map(link => (<li><Link to="/">{link.title}</Link></li>));
            
            return listLinks

        } else {
            console.log(err)
        }
    })
};
```

Comment: You are using a `Link` component outside the context of a `Router`. Check your console.

Comment: Also, you need to provide a unique `key` attribute to elements generated using `map`.

Comment: Thanks @OGreeni, I made an update to include a router. Still no luck. My console log shows the successful creation of the array through map, I just cannot seem to get it to render. There are no console log errors either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether this helps

I have not done any error handling, but ideally you should account for loading and error states as well.

If you get an error inside `useEffect` that it is unable to find scan on docClient or similar to it, put docClient in the dependency array, check for it inside the function and it should work.

```
import * as AWS from "aws-sdk";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

AWS.config.update({
  region: "some where",
  endpoint: "out there",
  accessKeyId: "key",
  secretAccessKey: "secret",
});

const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

export function DisplayTitles(props) {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  var params = {
    ProjectionExpression: "title",
    TableName: props.tableName,
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    docClient.scan(params, function (err, data) {
      if (data) {
        setData(data["Items"]);
      } else {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <ul>
      {data.map((link) => (
        <li key={link.id}>
          <Link to="/">
            {link.title}
          </Link>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much. I have been stuck on this for hours.